# Как передать данные из одного класса в другой через объект

Tags: java

Очень простой вопрос: Как передавать данные из `класса A` в `класс B` через `класс C`? Нужно это для передачи нескольких данных из класса в класс, чтобы впоследствии использовать данные в различных методах.

Использовать передачу данных через методы и конструкторы не хочу, потому что тогда у меня будет много методов с похожими заправаемыми данными.

Как я пытался реализовать свою идею:

```
class B{
    private int i;

    public int getIndex() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setIndex(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

class A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.setIndex(10);
    }
}

class C{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.getIndex());
    }
}
```

Я понимаю, что мне как-то надо добавить "ссылание объекта на самого себя" (Singleton), потому что `new B()` создает абсолютно новый класс и не учитывает данные, которые мы ввели в него до этого.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте попробуем разобраться. Есть класс и есть объекты на его основе. И данные передаются из объекта в объект, не в класс, класс это только шаблон для создания объектов.

Сама суть программирования на java это организовать взаимодействие объектов.

например у нас есть объект класса C с методом main, в котором и пишем код об этом взаимодействии.

```
class C {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B()
        b.setIndex(10);
        A a = new A(b);
        System.out.println(a.getIndex());
    }
}
```

В этом случае в классе A должен быть конструктор принимающий объекты типа B

```
class A{

    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void methodA(){
        System.out.println( b.getIndex() );
    }
}
```

Соответственно, теперь объект (типа A), получив через конструктор к себе (ссылку на) объект типа B ,может через геттер ( b.getIndex() ) получить необходимые данные и что-то с ними делать.

Comment: Можно ли без конструктора реализовать то, что вы написали? В моем вопросе говорится об неиспользовании конструктора

Comment: И вы уже в `классе C` передаете данные... А надо в `классе A` -> `класс B` -> `класс C`

Comment: Ну конечно можно. Воспользоваться сеттерами и геттерами. После того как у вас будут созданы объекты A и B и будут переменные хранящие на них ссылку вы можете вызывать все необходимые вам методы

Comment: Либо использовать в `С` `static` поля. Но это не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

> Как передавать данные из класса A в класс B через класс C? Использовать передачу данных через методы и конструкторы не хочу, потому что тогда у меня будет много методов с похожими заправаемыми данными.

Никак. Нарушается принцип Open/Closed (читать как SOLID)

> Использовать передачу данных через методы и конструкторы не хочу,
>   потому что тогда у меня будет много методов с похожими заправаемыми
>   данными.

Не будет. Используйте абстракции.

P.s. Тут должен быть пример, но я не до конца понимаю, что и зачем хочет автор